# Which one to choose as Project build target ? Google APIs or SDK platform

Tags: android, google-maps, android-build, android-version

I have been searching but couldn't find the difference between both of these things. I have read other questions in which people have said that we should use **Google Apis** as **build target** when we want to integrate **Google Maps Api** or use other Google apis.

The problem is that i am using maps on projects that were build on simple **Android 4.4** not **Google API (platform 4.4)** and the maps are working just fine on my Galaxy s3.

How are they possibly working?

And if they are working then what is the difference between Google APIs and SDK platform?
Or is the difference only related to emulators?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is really pointless to use the Google API's now because most if not all things included in that have been deprecated and moved to google play services. Selecting Google API will not do anything except maybe increase the size of your program. The difference being is in addition to the 4.4 SDK you would also get all the Google API stuff with it

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. I think this one is correct if anyone has other thoughts then i am open to suggestions. :)

Comment: I could not find anywhere on the net which says this. Can you provide a link?

Comment: @AppleGrew link for what?

Comment: @tyczj I did not find any reference which says Google Api target has been deprecated and is no longer required.

Comment: @AppleGrew did you even try not using the Google API to see what heppens?? if you did you clearly will see that you can use google maps without it. everything is in google play services now

Comment: @tyczj I am simply asking if you have any reference link or that it is something you just observed.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need (but it won't hurt you) to use Google APIs if you use Google Maps Android API v2. Google APIs is for when you work with deprecated Google Maps Android API v1 or you program [USB](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html).

Comment: Yes it wont hurt me but i didn't knew how to tell them apart as both performed in the same way for me. According to you its my choice whether i use Google API or not for non depricated maps (other APIs). but When i am working with depricated  maps (other APIs) then it is absolutely important to use Google APIs otherwise there will be crashes.

Answer (score 0):

The google API includes Google Maps and other Google-specific libraries. The Android one only includes core android libraries.

As for which one to choose, I would go with the Android API until you find that you need the Google API; such as when you need Google Maps functionality.

http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/index.html     is a link to the Google API page.

Comment: Like i said in my question "The problem is that i am using maps on projects that were build on simple Android 4.4 not Google API (platform 4.4) and the maps are working just fine on my Galaxy s3."

Comment: i didn't get you. please explain ?

Comment: so are you saying that i cannot use maps unless i am using Google API? (google-play-services_lib is also added and i think its the client library which provides the maps functionality)

Comment: please select Google API (platform 4.4)  in project->property->android->target android

Comment: i was asking for reason on why to select Google API as it isn't any different from Android 4.4. As both work for me so why we choose one over another

Comment: but its is show @dipali. U can try it. I have already tried it.