# Android difference betwen API: 19 Android 4.4 (Kitkat) and Google APIs (Google Inc.) (API 19)

Tags: android

Can any one tell what is difference between **API 19: Android 4.4 (KitKat)** and **Google APIs (Google Inc.) (API 19)** when we choose from Compile With: ??
[image: Can]

Comment: you must read this : http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From : [Difference between target google APIs and target android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914775/difference-between-target-google-apis-and-target-android%5D)

The google API includes Google Maps and other Google-specific libraries. The Android one only includes core android libraries.

As for which one to choose, you should go with the Android API until you find that you need the Google API; such as when you need Google Maps functionality.

Comment: copied from another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914775/difference-between-target-google-apis-and-target-android)

Answer (score 2):

Android api level 19 means the android os version (kitkat). It contains the standard android packages(from Android Open Source Projects). But the google api 19 is the android api 19+ google api's like google settings and other packages provided by google.

Answer (score 1):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914775/difference-between-target-google-apis-and-target-android), Google API includes Google Play Services like Maps, Play Store, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is really pointless to use the Google API's now because most if not all things included in that have been deprecated and moved to **google play services**.

Selecting Google API will not do anything except maybe increase the size of your program. The difference being is in addition to the 4.4 SDK you would also get all the Google API stuff with it.

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20546166/2419817).